# Is it always an indirect free after after misconduct by a player?

Tags: rules, football

According to the USSF's 'Advice to Referees', section 12.25:

> 12.25 RESTARTS FOR MISCONDUCT
>
> a. Offenses on the field of play If play is stopped solely to deal
>   with misconduct committed on the field by a player, the proper restart
>   is an indirect free kick taken from the location of the misconduct*.
>   If play is stopped for a foul in addition to misconduct, the restart
>   is determined by the foul. The restart cannot be a direct free kick
>   unless the reason for the stoppage included a direct free kick foul.
>   If misconduct occurs while play is stopped, the restart is determined
>   by the original reason for the stoppage. See also the table at Advice
>   5.19

Does this mean that **every** restart after a caution or send off is an indirect free kick?

Comment: I don't understand the negative score on this question. The premise is flawed, but in general, it's a useful question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, absolutely not. The section you're quoting applies *only* if "play is stopped solely to deal with misconduct". If play is stopped to deal with a foul, then "the restart is determined by the foul". This is all in the passage you've quoted.

Comment: Can you give an example of, 'when play is stopped solely to deal with misconduct'?

Comment: Read Law 12 "Fouls and misconduct" in the [Laws of the Game](http://www.thefa.com/~/media/files/pdf/the%20fa%202015-16/laws-of-the-game-2015-16.ashx).

Comment: @Anonymous There are many examples. Dissent committed by a player when the ball is in play, verbally distracting an opponent while the ball is in play, the goalkeeper throwing their shinguard at the ball in their penalty area while the ball is in play, performing a deliberate trick to circumvent the backpass restriction while the ball is in play.

Comment: Is it important to note that all these examples require the ball to be in play, or otherwise the restart remains as it would have been after the misconduct is dealt with.